# Authentication problem $user must be an instanceof UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.4 and have a weird problem with user authentication. Unfortunately, I myself cannot reproduce the problem, but I can see in the logs that it occurs with a small number of my users. The following error message occurs:

> $user must be an instanceof UserInterface, an object implementing a __toString method, or a primitive string

Stacktrace:

```
{
    "class": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "message": "$user must be an instanceof UserInterface, an object implementing a __toString method, or a primitive string.",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php:95",
    "trace": [
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php:224",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php:140",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AbstractListener.php:27",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall.php:139",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall.php:129",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall.php:97",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:304",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:264",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:239",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:122",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68",
        "/var/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:201",
        "/var/www/public/index.php:34"
    ]
}
```

I suspect that the token may not be renewable, the message mostly appears in the internal area. Sometimes it also appeared when the website was first accessed, where the user was probably not yet logged in.

My firewalls look like this:

```
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                username_parameter: login[username]
                password_parameter: login[password]
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            json_login:
                check_path: json_login_check
            provider: database
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            guard:
                provider: open_id
                authenticators:
                    - App\Path\To\OpenIdGuard
```

**login_check** is the default login action and **json_login_check** the login action via xhr. Additionally there are two user providers, the default one (**database**) and another one for open id (**open_id**).

The providers look like this:

```
    providers:
        database:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        open_id:
            id: App\Path\To\Provider
```

User entity (simplified):

```
class User implements \Serializable, UserInterface, EncoderAwareInterface
{
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getEmail();
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(''.mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
        $this->setEnabled(false);
        $this->roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
    }

    public function serialize(): string
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized): void
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Both providers (database and open_id) use the same User entity.

The problem occurs as I said only very rarely, in most cases, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was now able to find and solve the problem. As soon as a user group (ROLES) was changed, the error occurred because the session user could not be refreshed.

In order to allow a role change without the user being logged out or receiving an error message, a separate isEqualTo() method must be integrated in your User entity. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#comparing-users-manually-with-equatableinterface

Answer (score 1):

your object must implement `an object implementing a __toString method`
so you're missing toString method in it.
adding to `User` this method

```
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getUsername();
    }
```

should do. 
For reference, always check the original class:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php

EDIT: Since you have edited the question (by adding toString to it). I can say the problem with it might be that the getEmail may still render a null, which is not a string. Please change it to

```
        return (string) $this->getEmail();
```

If email is `null`, it will not fall into "primitive string" category. null is an object that doesn't implement UserInterface.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I stripped too much from the user entity. It has a __toString() method. I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. I will add (string) to the method to see if it works. Nevertheless email should never be null because I use it as username and the email property is defined as /** * @var string * * @Assert\Email() * @Assert\NotBlank() * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true) */ private $email;

Comment: that's not correct. I can think of at least this one scenario, but there might be more: When you create a User object (not saved to database yet), getEmail is null, because it was not set with a value yet. Therefore, Asserts are not yet fired at this point. Such object can still be used in your application logic and if you try to compare it with string, null is what you get, because that's what toString would return if not typecasted to string.

Comment: I think in that case a type error should be thrown instead of the authentication error, because null would be returned, but the return type is string.

Comment: that's a valid point, now that I think of it. So the case might be actually $user being badly instantiated as completely another class. might be worth to see what's being used in `AbstractToken.php:95` in that case.

Comment: Oddly enough, this seemed to be the cause. The error has not occurred since I added (string).

Comment: unfortunately the problem still occurs. the reason is that $user is actually NULL.

Comment: well, but I'm glad we solved other issues along the way :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue appears somewhere on production, so if you have any possibility to update the code directly on the server, please update it like this:

**Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken:**
(vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php)

```php
94.        if (!($user instanceof UserInterface || (\is_object($user) && method_exists($user, '__toString')) || \is_string($user))) {
95.            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$user must be an instanceof UserInterface, an object implementing a __toString method, or a primitive string. ' . get_class($user) . ' given.');
96.        }
```

to find out what exactly are you receivening in the `setUser()`.

I'm suspecting that you have `null` here, in `ContextListener`:

```php
222.                $refreshedUser = $provider->refreshUser($user);
223.                $newToken = clone $token;
224.                $newToken->setUser($refreshedUser);
```

if it's the case, then you should check what's going on `refreshUser()` method of your `UserProvider`.

Actually, it's the first place where I would put some logging to check what's going on.

Comment: You're right, $user is actually null. in the session ($ _SESSION) too. but the session key "_security_main" contains the user (json encoded). I don't have a refreshUser method for database users (only for openid users - the user with whom the problem occurred is not an openid user).